# How to write JSP Expression Tag in Scriptlet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

How to write expression tag inside the Scriptlet in JSP. I want to export data to Excel sheet.
I wrote the fallowing statement to JSP

```
<% response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=title.xls"); %>
```

here i m writing exported file name as 'title', here i want to change file name. so i write
like

```
<% String report=label.getLable('rep'); %>
```

How can i use 'report' variable in JSP Scrptlet ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use scriptlets. Use the JSP EL. Modifying the response headers and sending An Excel file should be done by a servlet, not by a JSP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the "report" variable.

```
<% String report=label.getLable('rep'); %>
<% response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + report); %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bit of [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) and [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) :

```
<c:set var="title" scope="request" value="<%=label.getLable('rep')%>"/>
<% response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=${title}.xls"); %>
```

Also read , [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Moreover , you can have a *Servlet* do this kind of job , not *JSP*.

The use of scriptlet is not advisable at all :

```
<% String report=label.getLable('rep') + ".xls"; 
   response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + report); %>
```

Comment: Thanks brother...  I used JSTL and EL but.. file name comes as {title}.xls on download dialogue box. I used second method above but filaname doesn't take full string (ex: filaname=something by simeone.xls). it only takes 'something' and extension is not coming, so it shows unsupported file format...

Answer (score 0):

You can use EL Expressions 
     ${}